# Is there any shortcut key to align code in Geany editor?

Tags: ide, geany

Am using Geany editor in ubuntu 13.10, Is there any shortcut key to align code (auto-alignment) in Geany editor?

For example : in Eclipse - Ctrl+Shift+F to invoke the Auto Formatter

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**For C, C++, C++/CLI, C#, and Java**

You can achieve a similar behavior with [Artistic Style 2.04](http://astyle.sourceforge.net/astyle.html).

1. [Download](http://sourceforge.net/projects/astyle/) the newest version, current 2.04 (do not use `apt-get` to install because then you will get the older version 2.03 and this version will not work for this scenario because it do not accept piped output)
2. Install Artistic Style -> follow the install doc (/astyle/doc/install.html) in the download (`make` then `make install`)
3. Add a custom command to Geany: 

   [image]

   [image]

   `bash -c "astyle --indent-classes -Y"` 

   To customize this look at the [Artistic Style documentation](http://astyle.sourceforge.net/astyle.html#_Indentation_Options)
4. Select an text area and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> to run the first Geany custom command 

   [image]

**For HTML**

You can use [tidy](http://tidy.sourceforge.net/), tidy can also compile your html code if you use geany.

1. Install tidy: `sudo apt-get install tidy`
2. Create a custom command (example): 

   `bash -c "tidy -xml --indent auto --indent-spaces 2 --quiet yes 2> /dev/null; true"`

More info:

- [Use HTML Tidy to just indent HTML code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7151180/use-html-tidy-to-just-indent-html-code)
- [Clean up your Web pageswith HTML TIDY](http://www.w3.org/People/Raggett/tidy/)
- [tidy man page](http://tidy.sourceforge.net/docs/tidy_man.html)
- [tidy Quick Reference](http://tidy.sourceforge.net/docs/quickref.html)

**For Python**

[Python Source Formatter/Pretty Printer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2913324/python-source-formatter-pretty-printer) (not tested)

Comment: thanks for your Answer,above solution will work only for C, C++, C#, and Java Source Code as per Artistic desc.please let me know this will work for HTML,Python?

Comment: @Sudheera updated answer

Comment: It worked for JavaScript as well.

Comment: For my `html` files, I used `bash -c "tidy --quiet yes -m --output-xhtml no --output-html yes --wrap 0 --tidy-mark no --indent auto %f > /dev/null; true" (Geany replaces the `%f` with the name + extension of the file). I think `2` is deprecated.

Comment: On Windows, use `cmd /c "astyle --indent-classes -Y"`

Comment: Where is it better to place the `astyle` folder on Linux?

Answer (score 2):

**For XML**
Go to Tools>Plugin manager and activate the plugin called XML PrettyPrinter. If that plugin is not available then search for it using apt or synaptic.

Once install, run by clicking Tools>PrettyPrinter XML.

Comment: works like charm!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use manual alignment using a pattern to align your code.
It's slower but works for any language.
There's a tclscript to do that posted here 
https://blog.jayvee-store.com/2017/06/18/code-alignment-in-geany/

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it using the vi editor:

1. Open the file in vi editor through terminal:

   ```
   vi sample.cpp
   ```
2. Change the mode to visual mode by pressing `v`.
3. Select the portion of the text you want to align by using the <kbd>Up</kbd> and <kbd>Down</kbd> arrow keys.
4. Press `+`.
5. Save and close:

   ```
   :wq!
   ```